# KeyError when indexing Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read data from a csv file into a pandas dataframe, and access the first column 'Date'

```
import pandas as pd
df_ticks=pd.read_csv('values.csv', delimiter=',')
print(df_ticks.columns)
df_ticks['Date']
```

produces the following result

```
Index([u'Date', u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume'], dtype='object')
KeyError: u'no item named Date'
```

If I try to acces any other column like 'Open' or 'Volume' it is working as expected

Comment: Can you post the header of your CSV file, to reproduce an example?

Comment: On the majority of questions I find on Stack Overflow pertaining to this topic, the error is usually attributed to a spelling error or leading/trailing whitespace. I'm surprised (a little shocked) that no one has mentioned either of these reasons until now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You most likely have an extra character at the beginning of your file, that is prepended to your first column name, `'Date'`. Simply Copy / Paste your output to a non-unicode console produces.

```
Index([u'?Date', u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 33):

As mentioned by alko, it is probably extra character at the beginning of your file.
When using [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), you can specify `encoding` to deal with encoding and heading character, known as [BOM (Byte order mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

```
df = pd.read_csv('values.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

This question finds some echoes on Stackoverflow: 
[Pandas seems to ignore first column name when reading tab-delimited data, gives KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806496/pandas-seems-to-ignore-first-column-name-when-reading-tab-delimited-data-gives)

Comment: is there something analogous for this for read_excel to alter all unicode column names and strip random whitespace? something as simple as this: str(col).strip() raises errors

Comment: I want to confirm the other answer listed here. pd.io.parsers.read_table('values.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig') I specifically had a byte-order-mark in the first line `\xef\xbb\xbf` or `\ufeff`.

Comment: I'm surprised that df.columns doesn't display this extra character!

Answer (score 5):

### It is almost always one of these reasons

1. You spelled the column name wrong
2. There are leading/trailing whitespaces

   - in this case, use `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` to remove them, or revisit your `pd.read_csv` (or other IO function) call to see if you can remove them while parsing input
3. Your column is not actually a column, but an index level

   - you can check the index level names using `df.index.names` to see if it is there. Calling `.reset_index()` before selecting the column should fix it.
4. Your DataFrame does not have the column, at all

   - it was all just a figment of your imagination. Please turn off your system and take a nap.

Regardless of the reason, the first step is to stop what you're doing and run `print(df.columns.tolist())` and eyeball the result to see which of these 4 possible reasons it could be.

Comment: Thanks for `print(df.columns.tolist())`. The leading/trailing whitespaces in column name were not visible otherwise.