# Pandas KeyError: Year for csv file dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar tot his one:

```
 BirthYear    Sex    Area    Count
2015         W      Dhaka    6
2015         M      Dhaka    3
2015         W      Khulna   1
2015         M      Khulna   8
2014         M      Dhaka    13
2014         W      Dhaka    20
2014         M      Khulna   9
2014         W      Khulna   6
2013         W      Dhaka    11
2013         M      Dhaka    2
2013         W      Khulna    8
2013         M      Khulna    5
2012         M      Dhaka    12
2012         W      Dhaka    4
2012         W      Khulna    7
2012         M      Khulna    1
```

now I want to create a barchart in Pandas where only the Male & Female born on 2015 will be shown.
The code :

```
df = pd.read_csv('out.csv')
df=df.reset_index()
df=df.loc[df["BirthYear"]==2015]
agg_df = df.groupby(['Sex']).sum()
agg_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
piv_df = agg_df.pivot(columns='Sex', values='Count')
piv_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

and after execution,IDLE shows this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4066)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3930)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: 'BirthYear'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sabid/Dropbox/Freelancing/data visualization python/pie.py", line 8, in <module>
    df=df.loc[df["StichtagDatJahr"]==2015]
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\sabid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4066)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3930)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: 'BirthYear'
```

I came to know from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731564/keyerror-when-indexing-pandas-dataframe) that it happens because the 'BirthYear' column name has some header before it.
But I don't know how to remove the header and make the code work.
Is there any fruitful solution for this?

Comment: [The solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23733522/5741205) has been provided in the link, you've posted - did you try it?

Comment: What do you mean by "some header before it?" If you mean that there's a a space at the start of the string?

Comment: @MaxU I tried it but that does not really work...the error comes on again and again

Comment: @Batman I think there are some charecter before it

Comment: @SabidBinHabib, can you post an output of `print(df.columns.tolist())` just after calling `pd.read_csv(...)`?

Comment: @MaxU yes,but the output is weird. 

['\ufeff"BirthYear"', '"Sex"', '"Area"', '"Count"']

Comment: @SabidBinHabib, so you didn't try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23733522/5741205) - didn't you?

Comment: @SabidBinHabib, what is your pandas version? Pandas 0.19.0 should be able to fix this problem automatically

Comment: @MaxU 0.18.1 that's why it happenned.
however thanks for your solution.It worked finally.

Comment: @MaxU if you are familiar with MatPlotLib,can you please look at this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442771/matplotlib-barchart-and-pie-chart-representation-in-the-same-figure?noredirect=1#comment68134254_40442771

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127455/discussion-between-sabid-bin-habib-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the columns.

```
df.rename(columns=["BirthYear", "Sex", "Area", "Count"], inplace=True)
```

Comment: I would also say replace `df=df.reset_index()` with `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`. Setting `drop` to false will make the previous index appear as a new column named `index`.

Comment: @Batman, `df.rename(columns=list)` will produce `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Test this: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2),columns=list('ab')); df.rename(columns=['X','Y'])`

Comment: @Jakub it shows error:

    df.loc[df["BirthYear"]==2015]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: @MaxU same error is shown again : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You should be able to use a list. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#pandas.DataFrame.rename If you're using an older version of Pandas you can use a `dict`, or just `df.columns=["BirthYear", "Sex", "Area", "Count"]`

Comment: @Batman, here is a way how to use a list: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,2),columns=list('ab')); df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: ['X','Y'][df.columns.get_loc(x)])`. But the proper solution would be to specify correct encoding with BOM

Comment: @Batman thanks for your kind support,but MaxUs solution worked here and I think that's the correct approach.
Thank you all for your co-operation,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want output like this:

[image: Barplot]

I am not sure about this, but I think using the `pivot` method messed you up. You don't need to use `pivot` because `agg_df` is basically a pivot table. Here is the code I used to create that graph:

```
import pandas as pd

# I made this to approximate your CSV file.
table = {
    'BirthYear': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014,],
    'Sex': ['W', 'M', 'W', 'M', 'M', 'W',],
    'Area': ['Dhaka', 'Dhaka', 'Khulna', 'Khulna', 'Dhaka', 'Dhaka',],
    'Count': [6, 3, 1, 8, 13, 20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(table)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Select people born in 2015.
df = df.loc[df["BirthYear"] == 2015]

# This is basically a pivot table.
agg_df = df.groupby(['Sex']).sum()

# Make the plot.
agg_df['Count'].plot.bar(stacked=True)
```