# select one column of a data frame pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, select, dataframe

I am trying to select a column from a pandas data frame I am reading

```
tweets = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PedroLuis\Documents\Manita\LASSO 20170219-20170402.csv', sep = " , ", engine='python')
tweets = pd.DataFrame(tweets)
```

When I list the columns what I see is

```
    list(tweets)
Out: ['"","text","favorited","favoriteCount","replyToSN","created","truncated","replyToSID","id","replyToUID","statusSource","screenName","retweetCount","isRetweet","retweeted","longitude","latitude"']
```

I try to select the second column by its name>

```
tweets['text']
```

And I get this error:

> KeyError: 'text'

Comment: That is strange.  What happens when you try `tweets.iloc[:,1]`?  ps. you don't need the `tweets = pd.DataFrame(tweets)` line because read_csv() already returns a dataframe

Comment: What is output for tweets.columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space in your sep = " , " which causes all the column to combine.

Change it to

```
tweets = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\PedroLuis\Documents\Manita\LASSO 20170219-20170402.csv', sep = ",", engine='python')
```

You should be able to call tweet['text']

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the output of list(), you'll notice one entire string contained in single quotes, and each header surrounded in double-quotes, which means pandas hasn't interpreted the line as you are expecting.

```
Out: ['"","text","favorited","favoriteCount","replyToSN","created","truncated","replyToSID","id","replyToUID","statusSource","screenName","retweetCount","isRetweet","retweeted","longitude","latitude"']
```

Whereas it should look like

```
Out: ['','text','favorited','favoriteCount','replyToSN','created','truncated','replyToSID','id','replyToUID','statusSource','screenName','retweetCount','isRetweet','retweeted','longitude','latitude']
```

I don't know what your input looks like, but, as Niche.P says, cleaning up your separator parameter could be a solution. Otherwise it could be an [encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731564/keyerror-when-indexing-pandas-dataframe).