# Using Pandas data frame assign values from one column to a variable using another variable for the column name

Tags: python, pandas

In C# I'm sending in the following which is sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDXdh.png):

```
string depVar = "Cover_Type";
```

In Python I'm trying to accomplish the following using a Pandas data frame.  The example code below fails...is there a way to do this?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd    
import sys

dependent_var = sys.argv[1]
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
y = df[dependent_var]
```

**EDIT**
In my attempt to keep the details simple it sounds like I left out essential information (newbie mistake) so thank you for your patience.

(1)Here's a sample of the data:
[image]

***Goal:*** The most important piece of info I left out (again sorry) was that I'm passing in the variable from another program, so my goal is definitely to use the variable value and not just print out the value.

I believe one of the answers provided is very close and actually answered my original question.  BUT it doesn't solve my problem because the variable being passed in is a string and I'm thinking now that it needs to be converted to a list hence the need for the square brackets.

**Error: KeyError: "['Flower_Type']"**

Printing out columns:

```
Index(['Id', 'Elevation', 'Aspect', 'Slope',
       'Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology',
       'Flower_Type'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Final Answer:**

```
import csv
import pandas as pd    
import sys

depVar= sys.argv[1] # had to assign the incoming variable to a new variable
a = []
a.append(depVar)

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
y = df[a]
```

Comment: What is the error you receive? Is it `KeyError`?  (add the traceback to the question)

Comment: Print out the output of `df.columns`

Comment: seems like the `train.csv` either doesnt have the column `Flower_Type` or has preceeding or succeeding spaces in the name. You can fix the spaces using `str.strip()` and try again.

Comment: It's definitely a column...the code works if i use the column name like so, y = df['Flower_Type']

Comment: @Carlisle, what's your end motive , Just only to print / get coulmn `Flower_Type`? or to test a variable passing through df?

Comment: @ALollz, I will provide the sample data to reproduce the problem as well as the error.  Plz give me some time to provide this before closing.  Thanks.

Comment: @ALollz yes, KeyError.  Plz see edits and thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Based on the `KeyError` you receive, it seems like you somehow have `dependent_var` equal to the string `"['Flower_Type']"`, and not just `'Flower_Type'`. Are you somehow converting it to a list then making that list a string somewhere?

Comment: @anky_91, that's not true ,  ops dataframe columns print  doesn't shows this rathers its correct ?

Comment: @Carlisle, just try `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())` or  `[['Flower_Type']]` and see .

Comment: how does `sys.argv[1].strip('[]')[1:-1]` work instead of `sys.argv[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need below:

You need to quote column name inside `[]` .

```
dependent_var = ['Flower_Type']
```

then

```
y = df[dependent_var]
```

### Debugging process:

You can try like `[['Flower_Type']]` it works if your csv contains spaces in the header or alternatively you can tim any confronting spaces of the cells.

`df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())`

OR:

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding="utf-8")
```

OR use [Byte order mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731564/keyerror-when-indexing-pandas-dataframe/23733522) as mentioned here

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

In this case it might make sense to use a list comprehension to strip all of the extra spaces.

```
df.columns = [col.strip() for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: it should work without it `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2]}), y = 'a', df[y]` has no issue.

Comment: @ALollz, that's correct , but OP should avoid variable at first place even it can be processed  while reading csv

Comment: Agreed, that's why i asked OP the end motive to use it in the comment section. There are many things  needs to be considered based on the requirement but POST should be concrete enough to stay with objectives to achieve though.

Comment: dependent_var is being passed in from another program as a string.  I updated my original post with more details.

Comment: @pygo bracketing the variable is not required, you can just assign the name without the bracket and it should still work. Try it out on a sample dataframe you have

Comment: @anky_91, that i know it works, however, looks like csv contained spaces in the header.

Comment: @Carlisle, can you try like `[['Flower_Type']]` it works if there  csv contained spaces in the header,  you can trim() to clip any spaces of the cells. like `df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strip())`

Comment: that is exactly what i had assumed in the comments. :)

Comment: @pygo thank you for the help...I think it was your post that led me to the final answer which I updated in the post.  I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.  I'm happy to give you credit for this but that might be misleading since my solution was different.

Comment: @ALollz Agree with you...thank you for working through this with me everyone.  I tried to delete the post but it will not allow it.  Error: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Just go straight with

```
y = df['Flower_Type']
```

Why does it have to be stored in a variable?

Comment: this is correct at the first place OP should avoid using variable.