# sub-selecting panda dataframe with special character

Tags: python, dataframe, special-characters

I am quite new to `python`. I try to get subselect a dataframe from a dataframe base on column

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv',sep=";")
```

then I try

```
df = df['Scanner Typique Covid (Oui/Non)']
```

and I get

```
KeyError: 'Scanner Typique Covid (Oui/Non)'
```

I tryied to add `encoding = 'utf-8'` as an argument for `read_csv` method, with no success. Someone has an idea ?

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731564/keyerror-when-indexing-pandas-dataframe/23733522 might help. To give us more information, could you include a sample of your CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a / in front of the /

```
df = df['Scanner Typique Covid (Oui//Non)']
```

If that doesn't work, try adding another /

Comment: still getting the same issue