# Not able to display the column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I am trying to print a single column of my data set it is showing errors

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2645             try:
> -> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Label'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 data['Label']
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
> **getitem**(self, key)    2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:    2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2801             if is_integer(indexer):    2802                 indexer = [indexer]
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2646                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(key)    2647             except KeyError:
> -> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2649
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
> 2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Label'

```
data['Label']
```

*[image: I have successfully read the csv and there exists a column named label idk why it is not able to read it. I am attaching a picture as well.]*

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65437775/14289892

Comment: Thanks, Anurag it was due to the trailing white spaces.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `anaconda` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that the column name is having trailing spaces. Just try to print the column names & verify.

`print(data.columns)`

or try to print the columns after

`data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: Thanks, pal it worked the same thing was also suggested by Anurag Dabas. Kudos to both of you

Answer (score 0):

If you have DataFrame and would like to access or select a specific few rows/columns from that DataFrame, you can use square brackets.

Now suppose that you want to select a column from the data(as per your question) DataFrame.

```
data["Label"]
```

But if you are unaware of the columns. You can get a column list and then display column data.

```
columns = data.columns.values.tolist()
data[columns[index]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **data.index** if you want to print the Label column.