# Python pandas producing error when trying to access 'DATE' column on large data set

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a file with 3'502'379 rows and 3 columns. The following script is supposed to be executed but raises and error in the date handling line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas

path = 'data_prices.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=';')
data['DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
```

This is the error that occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4066)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3930)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: 'DATE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\data\script.py", line 15, in <module>
    data['DATE'] = pandas.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4066)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3930)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12408)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12359)
KeyError: 'DATE'
```

Comment: Still problem if use `data = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=';', nrows=10000)` ?

Comment: your `data` df doesn't have `DATE` column. Please post the output of `data.columns.tolist()`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is the output: `['\ufeffDATE', 'TICKER', 'PRICE']` This is weird, the file itself does definitely not start with this.

Comment: it's a UTF BOM signature

Comment: @Spurious this is worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806496/pandas-seems-to-ignore-first-column-name-when-reading-tab-delimited-data-gives

Comment: You have utf-16 Big endian BOM, see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774705/pandas-dataframe-finding-index-value-for-a-column try: `data = pandas.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='utf-16')`

Answer (score 4):

the `'\ufeffDATE'` in the first column name shows that your CSV file has a [UTF-16 Byte Order Mark (BOM) signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) so it must be read accordingly.

so try this when reading your CSV:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

or as [@EdChum suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846590/python-pandas-producing-error-when-trying-to-access-date-column-on-large-data/38846829#comment65058304_38846590):

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=';', encoding='utf-16')
```

both variants should work properly

PS [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17912811/5741205) shows how to deal with BOMs

Comment: Wrong, this is utf-16 big endian: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding `FE FF` is utf-16 Big endian

Comment: @EdChum, i've corrested my answer. Actually both variants will work properly